Why is `Minimize` function not working when expression has parameters and trigonometric functions?
I have been trying to minimize a simple function using Mathematica 13.3
$$\frac{4}{2} N \sin ^2\left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right) \left(\left(\frac{N}{2}+1\right) \sin ^2\left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right)-1\right)$$
where $N>0$ is just a parameter and I am interested in achieving the minima with respect to  $\theta$. I tried to compute this in mathematica using the lines
Minimize[{4 N/2 Sin[\[Theta]/2]^2 ((N/2 + 1) Sin[\[Theta]/2]^2 - 1), 
  N > 0}, \[Theta]]

But was presented with the output
Minimize[{2 N Sin[\[Theta]/2]^2 (-1 + (1 + N/2) Sin[\[Theta]/2]^2), 
  N > 0}, \[Theta]

(which is same as the input!). However, when I tried to substitute $\sin(\theta)$ with a dummy variable x , I was able to attain a sensible output which reads :
.
Now I am faced with two problems

Even though the minimum value of the function given matches what we had calculated by hand, I cannot interpret the value of $x_{\rm{min}}$ presented. The part that reads $\frac{2 N}{2 N+4}$ is what I expected, but I cannot interpret the extra terms which look like : #1^2 and #1^4 &, 1
I want to do the same but for an expression that has two angles $(\theta,\phi)$ and the expression looks like $$\frac{1}{16} N \left(N \left(-8 \cos (\theta ) \cos (\phi )-\left(N^2+N-2\right) \cos (2 \phi )+4 N \sin (\theta ) \sin (\phi )\right)+N \left(N^2+N+4\right)+2 (N+2) \cos (2 \theta )-4\right)$$ which makes an algebraic substitution much harder.

Please let me know what can possibly be done to fix the situation where the output produced is just the input cell itself so that the procedure can be generalized to functions involving more than one trigonometric variables.
EDIT 1
I understand that N is a reserved word in Mathematica so I should have used some other symbol as a parameter. I tried that, but the same problem seems to persist. Below is the output attained :


Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. N is a reserved word. Please use a different symbol that starts with a lowercase character as built-in names start with uppercase letters. Thanks.

I had already tried using the symbol a which is unreserved instead of N , but it gave the same problem.

Because the function you are minimizing is not polynomial, it does not always work. Even with adding constraints I could not make it work also. But NMinimize works, but need to give numerical value for your a variable.  So this works a = 3; NMinimize[{4  a/2  Sin[x/2]^2  ((a/2 + 1)  Sin[x/2]^2 - 1)}, x] and gives {-0.6,{x->-7.21048}} may be there is a trick to make it work with your function. Do not know now.

The term "Root[...]" is a root object. This is an accurate algebraic number. Look it up in the help.  If you replace N by a numerical value you can get an approximate machine number using e.g the operator.: "N

Since you don't have any obvious denominators Reduce[f'[θ]==0&&f''[θ]>0&&n>0,θ] quickly returns (θ==2*Pi*C[1]-2*ArcTan[Sqrt[1/(1+n)]]||θ==2*Pi*C[1]+2*ArcTan[Sqrt[1/(1+n)]]) Can you think how to do something similar with your two variable problem.
